# No route found when using POST with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, routes

So I'm working on a simple Ruby on Rails application. Its actually based off an official tutorial that you can find at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html. I'm extending the testing past the scope of the tutorial. The testing framework used is SimpleCov.

```
    3) Error:
CommentsControllerTest#test_Rcomment_-_Create_(S):
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"/articles/201799169/:create", :comment=>{:alias=>"Somebody", :text=>"Some plain text"}, :controller=>"comments"}
    test/controllers/comments_controller_test.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <class:CommentsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/comments_controller_test.rb:12:in `block in <class:CommentsControllerTest>'



    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                       Controller#Action
       welcome_index GET    /welcome/index(.:format)                          welcome#index
                root GET    /                                                 welcome#index
    article_comments GET    /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                     POST   /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                     PATCH  /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     PUT    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     DELETE /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
            articles GET    /articles(.:format)                               articles#index
                     POST   /articles(.:format)                               articles#create
         new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                           articles#new
        edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                      articles#edit
             article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#show
                     PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#update
                     PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#update
                     DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                           articles#destroy




 test "Rcomment - Create (S)" do
    article = articles(:valid)
    article.save
    assert_difference('Comment.count') do
      post '/articles/' + article.id.to_s + '/:create', comment: { alias: 'Somebody', text: 'Some plain text' }
    end
    assert_response :redirect
    assert_redirected_to article_path(assigns(:article))
  end
```

Comment: Paste you controllers code

Comment: You just POST against articles/{articleId}/comments, just like line 4 of your routes says to. What the heck is '/:create' in there for?

Answer (score 0):

There method you try to post to does not exist. You need to post to `:create`:

```
post :create, article_id: article.id, 
     comment: { alias: 'Somebody', text: 'Some plain text' }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately this suggestion does not work. I still get "No route matches {:action=>"/articles/201799169/comments", :comment=>{:alias=>"Somebody", :text=>"Some plain text"}, :controller=>"comments"}".